# Spring MVC and Hibernate integration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having problems integrating Spring MVC and Hibernate.

I assume I am missing some configuration to tell Spring to use Hibernate, because there aren't any errors when running the application, yet the database is not updated with my entities.

In `main/webapp/WEB-INF`, I have 3 configuration files:

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-configuration.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.mypackage.controller"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

spring-configuration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        ">

    <!-- Placeholder config -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.mypackage.dao"/>

    <!-- Data source -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.mypackage.model" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The `database.properties`:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
jdbc.username=root1
jdbc.password=password

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

In the `org.mypackage.model` package, I have a class annotated with `@Entity`. The database exists, the user exists as well. When I run my application, the database is not updated with a new table that corresponds to my class. How can I fix this?

EDIT 1:

Output when running the application (server starting omitted, no errors):

```
INFO: Server startup in 157 ms
Connected to server
[2015-10-11 04:17:57,948] Artifact project:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
2015-10-11 16:18:00,274  INFO DispatcherServlet:484 - FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
2015-10-11 16:18:00,298  INFO XmlWebApplicationContext:510 - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sun Oct 11 16:18:00 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-10-11 16:18:00,342  INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
2015-10-11 16:18:01,066  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Mapped "{[/person/add],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.mypackage.controller.PersonController.home()
2015-10-11 16:18:01,067  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Mapped "{[/person/save],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String org.mypackage.controller.PersonController.save(org.mypackage.model.Person,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
2015-10-11 16:18:01,069  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:220 - Mapped "{[/hello],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.mypackage.controller.HelloController.hello()
2015-10-11 16:18:01,119  INFO Version:27 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.3.Final
2015-10-11 16:18:01,342  INFO RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:523 - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sun Oct 11 16:18:00 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-10-11 16:18:01,386  INFO RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:523 - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sun Oct 11 16:18:00 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-10-11 16:18:01,492  INFO DispatcherServlet:503 - FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 1215 ms
[2015-10-11 04:18:01,516] Artifact project:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-10-11 04:18:01,516] Artifact project:war exploded: Deploy took 3 568 milliseconds
2015-10-11 16:18:02,723  WARN PageNotFound:1120 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>project</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: can you post the log output when you start the application?

Comment: Why did you use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` ? This produces a container-managed EntityManagerFactory.  Have a look on  `LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` - application-managed EntityManagerFactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve created a simple application using **Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE**.

The application is running from the main method of the `App.class`.

The configuration used was similar to yours, the only difference being the database choosen (postgresql instead of mysql).

In the example, an additional bean was created called `jpaVendorAdapter`. The configuration is as follows:

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
</bean>
```

**com.stackoverflow.App**

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/Datasource.xml");
    }

}
```

**resources/properties/database.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spring
jdbc.username=postgres
jdbc.password=abc123
```

**resources/spring/Datasource.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.stackoverflow.model"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! One additional question, however. Can the Datasource.xml context file be loaded from another .xml file? Or only from the `main()` method?

Comment: Sure it can! You can load if from other XML files as usual. Just use `<import resource="PATH_TO_XML.XML"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can change your properties this

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

to this

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

Your DB will be created from zero. You may want to take the back up of your db before doing this.

Comment: That didn't work. I also cannot see anything related to Hibernate in logs when the application is started. How can I test the connection in some other way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the "annotatedClasses" property? I remember having the same issue before since it didn't seem to get the annotated classes so I solved it with that property, the usage below:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
                hibernate.format_sql = true
                hibernate.show_sql = true
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>org.company.project.model.User</value>
                <value>org.company.project.model.Document</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="packagesToScan"> -->
        <!-- <list> -->
        <!-- <value>org.company.project.model</value> -->
        <!-- </list> -->
        <!-- </property> -->
    </bean>
```